# Controller methods do not call when opening link on a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my angular app I have a link when clicked I am navigated to a page .

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">         
                                <li ng-class="{'current':isCurrent('/home')}">
                                    <a href="#home" >Home</a> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

It works fine , but when I open the link on a new tab by right click . Then the page is loaded but its controller methods are not getting loaded.
I am not having any idea why this is happening.

```
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'DashboardController as dashboard'
    });
```

controller

```
(function() {
function DashboardController($filter) {

    this.retrieveData = function() {

        // data is retrieved from server here
    };

    this.initPage = function() {
        ctrl.retrieveData();
    };

        ctrl.initPage();

}
angular.module('esg.controllers').controller('DashboardController', ['$filter', DashboardController]);
```

})();

Comment: Try to change `href="#home"` to `href="#/home"`.

Comment: Can you paste your `controller` and `routing` code ?

Comment: is the route in the new tab same as when you click it on same page ?